# Core Data Pre-populated SQLite issue, z-metadata 

Tags: sqlite, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I have this issue with Core Data. I am creating a core-data-based application, for one of the tabs, to populate a UITableViewController. Basically, I have read somewhere that there is an issue with providing a pre-populated sqllite file to be used to load up the data. I created a pre-populated data file and at first had issues with Z_METADATA and other anomalies like that. If we are creating our own sqllite file, is there somethign we have to include, such as certain table names etc?

Note, I didnt create teh application with use core data for storage ticked at beginning, so im not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doron, take a look and [A Blog On Tech](http://ablogontech.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/using-a-pre-populated-sqlite-database-with-core-data-on-iphone-os-3-0/) for a really great example of how to get what you are trying to do. Basically it's best to let Xcode create the base SQLite DB for you, copy it to your code directory, pre-populate your data there and then finally add it to the project through Xcode.

So while it is possible to work a Core Data application that you haven't created from the beginning in Xcode it is much easier to start from there.